# sqlalchemy no specified driver, however driver is specified

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

According to this [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc), sqlalchemy now needs to specify a driver. I have done so based on the example yet it still says I haven't. I'm using windows authentication.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{SERVER}/{DATABASENAME}?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0')
```

This of course works. However, when you try to use the connection in pandas doing something like:

```
df = pandas.read_sql(sql=query_string, con=engine)
```

It generates a `DBAPIError`:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of connecting to an existing MS SQL database with a table called TableA with two parameters name and description.  I have also added an example of how to create a query and get back a pandas dataframe.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@{SERVER}/{database}?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0?trusted_connection=yes")
metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tableA'
    name = Column('name', String, primary_key=True)
    desc = Column('description', String)


Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()

q = session.query(TableA)

df = pd.read_sql(q.statement, q.session.bind)
```

Comment: actually in this case it's a query string. I'll update it to account for this.

Comment: what kind of authentication does your mssql server require?  For windows based authentication, I used the following string.

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@{SERVER}/{DATABASE}?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0?trusted_connection=yes")

Comment: windows authentication. it's an analytics database.

Comment: If you add the ?trusted_connection=yes and the @ before the server name does it work now?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.  Hopefully that will help you get it working.

Comment: @tornesi - you are a life saver. I spent the whole weekend trying all kind of ways to connect to my first time new MS SQL installation locally, with no success, until I read your post. My problem was, and dozens of other post do not have it, is the '@' at the beginning of the string connection. Once I put it I was able to connect to the database using db model of sqlalchemy