# Sqlalchemy complaining of no driver even though driver is specified

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's the code, chosen to parallel [sqlalchemy no specified driver, however driver is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749601/sqlalchemy-no-specified-driver-however-driver-is-specified) :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{URL}/{database_name}?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes'
db = create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING)
db.echo = False
metadata = MetaData(db)
connection = db.connect()
```

... and here's the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've checked the ODBC drivers in the system, and I've named it correctly.  Does anyone have any further advice on how to specify the driver?  (I should note that this code works as expected on an older system with SQL Server Native Client 10.0, and without specifying the driver.  Leaving out the driver specification on the newer system causes the same error.)

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: Thank you!  SQL Server Native Client 11.0 is in that list.  (There are others, too.  Is there one I should be seeking to default to in general?)

Comment: Try changing `?trusted_connection=yes` to `&trusted_connection=yes`